# Persistência com Doctrine não leva dados do object para o insert

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine, orm, persistência

Comecei um projeto novo em PHP onde toda base de dados está com as tabelas e suas colunas com nomes diferentes das classes e seus atributos.

Com a intenção de ganhar na produtividade de não ficar renomeando resolvi aplicar o Doctrine ORM (não tenho experiência com ele), entretanto estou com o seguinte problema.

```
<?php  

/**
 * Entity
 * Table(name="usuario")
 */
class Usuario {...}
```

Comment: Só uma dica pro uso do site: use o título para descrever o problema, aquele monte de tags é só ruído; o site usa o sistema de tags para classificar o conteúdo; a falta da tag PHP faz com que o código não apareça colorido. Na verdade, parece que colocou as tags principais no título e as secundárias como tags de verdade; a falta das tags principais dificulta que os especialistas daquelas tags encontrem sua pergunta.

Comment: Olá caro amigo, agradeço pelas dicas. Alterações realizadas. TKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Senhores.

Identifiquei o erro lamentável.

Notem o mapeamento:

/**
 * Entity
 * Table(name="usuario")
 */
class Usuario {...}

Faltava o "@" antes. 
Devido ao substituir texto da IDE acabei não percebendo isso e o erro apontado não era explícito.

Portando ficou assim:

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="usuario")
 */
class Usuario {...}

Obrigado a todos.